# OSX Clipboard is broken in Vim

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, clipboard

I have OSX ML and Vim 7.3. When I try to use OSX clipboard...well nothing happens.

If I do `"+yy` for instance, nothing gets into osx clipboard. `"*` doesn't work either, neither does ex command yaking to register's + and *. Pasting into Vim from OSX clipboard doesn't work either.

Also, `:set clipboard=unnamed` doesn't work either (supposed to sync unnamed register with osx clipboard). It doesn't work in iTerm nor System Terminal.

I have no problems on my Linux box.

EDIT: I just found out my Vim isn't compiled with clipboard:

```
jan@rmbp:~$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jun 20 2012 13:16:02)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path 
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv 
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent 
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape 
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse 
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs 
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
jan@rmbp:~$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS X Mountain Lion the pre installed version of vim does not include clipboard support.

You can check this by doing.

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
```

You should see a lines that looks like this

```
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
-xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

The `-clipbaord` means that vim isn't compiled with clipboard support.

The easiest fix to this is to use MacPorts (or your favorite package manager) and install vim through that

OR

install MacVim. MacVim is a Mac's equivalent of gvim. It also comes with a script called mvim that has a flag that allows you to use the command line vim that comes with MacVim. The command is `mvim -v`

Then you can alias `mvim -v` to `vim`. (You can put this in your .bashrc)

```
alias vim='mvim -v'
```

Comment: I depend on terminal vim so I installed it via brew, and it compiled with clipboard. Thanks.

Comment: still doesn't work for me, even with clipboard support compiled in